# Match double hyphens in comments of malformed XML

Tags: regex, pcre, autoit

I'm to parse XML files that do not conform to the "no [double hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hyphen) in comments" -standard, which makes MSXML complain. I am looking for a way of deleting offending hyphens.

I am using [`StringRegExpReplace()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExpReplace.htm). I attempted following regular expressions:

```
<!--(.*)--> : correctly gets comments
<!--(-*)--> : fails to be a correct regex (also tried escaping and using \x2D)
```

Given the right pattern, I would call:

```
StringRegExpReplace($xml_string,$correct_pattern,"") ;replace with nothing
```

How to match remaining extra hyphens within an XML comment, while leaving the remaining text alone?

Comment: Just to clarify, the regex is required to match any number of hyphens above 2.

Comment: Sorry but I find your question totally unclear. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to delete all hyphens inside an xml comment? Could you add an input string and the expected result?

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML comments that are my I/O are not being displayed in my post, even when signaled as a code-block. [link](http://pastebin.com/9qNcjvdP).

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to remove extraneous hyphens (double, triple, and so on), from within an XML comment, whether they are at the beginning (<!--- invalid-->), in the middle of (<-- inval--id-->), at the end of (<--invalid----->) or any combination of the above, such that, at the end of my regexreplace call I am left with a well-formed XML comment, parsable by MSXML A comment can span several lines.

Comment: The reason your -* regex fails might be because of backtracking.  You can learn more about that at http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?|\G(?!\A)(?|-{2,}+([^->][^-]*)|(-[^-]+)|-+(?=-->)|-->[^<]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|[^<]*<+(?>[^<]+<+)*?(?:!--\K|[^<]*\z\K(*ACCEPT))(?|-*+([^->][^-]*)|-+(?=-->)|-?+([^-]+)|-->[^<]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)()))
```

details:

```
(?| 
    \G(?!\A) # contiguous to the precedent match (inside a comment)

    (?|
        -{2,}+([^->][^-]*) # duplicate hyphens, not part of the closing sequence
      |
         (-[^-]+)          # preserve isolated hyphens 
      |
         -+ (?=-->)        # hyphens before closing sequence, break contiguity
      |
         -->[^<]*          # closing sequence, go to next <
         (*SKIP)(*FAIL)    # break contiguity
    )
  |
    [^<]*<+ # reach the next < (outside comment)
    (?> [^<]+ <+ )*?       # next < until !-- or the end of the string 
    (?: !-- \K | [^<]*\z\K (*ACCEPT) ) # new comment or end of the string
    (?|
        -*+ ([^->][^-]*)   # possible hyphens not followed by >
      |
        -+ (?=-->)         # hyphens before closing sequence, break contiguity
      |
        -?+ ([^-]+)        # one hyphen followed by >
      |
        -->[^<]*           # closing sequence, go to next <
        (*SKIP)(*FAIL) ()  # break contiguity (note: "()" avoids a mysterious bug
    )                      # in regex101, you can remove it)
)
```

With this replacement: `\1`

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS5wC0/8)

The `\G` feature ensures that matches are consecutive.
Two ways are used to break the contiguity:

- a lookahead `(?=-->)`
- the backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` that forces the pattern to fail and all characters matched before to not be retried.

So when contiguity is broken or at the begining the first main branch will fail (cause of the `\G` anchor) and the second branch will be used.

`\K` removes all on the left from the match result.

`(*ACCEPT)` makes the pattern succeed unconditionnaly.

This pattern uses massively the branch reset feature `(?|...(..)...|...(..)...|...)`, so all capturing groups have the same number (in other words there is only one group, the group 1.)

Note: even this pattern is long, it needs few steps to obtain a match. The impact of non-greedy quantifiers is reduced as much as possible, and each alternatives are sorted and as efficient as possible. One of the goals is to reduce the total number of matches needed to treat a string.

Comment: In my actual test-case, it works great for the WEAPON INFO line, but fails to remove trailing -'s in the example: https://regex101.com/r/pD6hW5/4 This contains a lot of tabs.

Comment: Another exception: https://regex101.com/r/pD6hW5/13 This is becoming a quest for the Holy Grail. Sorry to keep doing this to you. From what I understand, your regex assumes that <!-- within an existing comment is the start of a comment, when it is in fact, just text.I *think* this messes it up.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<!<!)--+(?!-?>)(?=(?:(?!-->).)*-->)
```

matches `--` (or `----` etc.) only between `<!--` and `-->`. You need to set the `/s` parameter to allow the dot to match newlines.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!<!)   # Assert that we're not right at the start of a comment
--+       # Match two or more dashes --
(?=       # only if the following can be matched further onwards:
 (?!-?>)  # First, make sure we're not at the end of the comment.
 (?:      # Then match the following group
  (?!-->) # which must not contain -->
  .       # but may contain any character
 )*       # any number of times
 -->      # as long as --> follows.
)         # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qX1nR9/2).

I suppose the correct AutoIt syntax would be

```
StringRegExpReplace($xml_string, "(?s)(?<!<!)--+(?!-?>)(?=(?:(?!-->).)*-->)", "")
```

Comment: One last slight problem...In the case of https://regex101.com/r/qX1nR9/3 (multiple dashes immediately following the start of comment), one additional dash is removed, leaving an invalid "<-" start of comment. Regex master to the rescue?:)

Comment: Tricky; PCRE doesn't fully support variable-length lookbehind assertions. The following might work: `(?<!<!|<!-)--+(?!-?>)(?=(?:(?!-->).)*-->)`, but it will leave `<!--- foo -->` alone. `<!---- foo -->` and up will be handled correctly.

Comment: Also turns <!---- WEAPON INFO ---> into <!-- WEAPON INFO ---> but did not error out in AutoIt's PCRE. https://regex101.com/r/qX1nR9/4 signals an error.